# RPi.GPIO is never reachable after upgrade to Python3

Tags: python, rpi.gpio, update

yesterday I run an install of `Python3` on my Raspberry Pi 3. The preinstalled Python version was 2.7.1
If I run a scrip now, i reveive the following error message:

```
import RPi.GPIO
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'RPi'
```

Some additional Information:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/Python-3.6.0 $ pwd
/home/pi/Python-3.6.0
pi@raspberrypi:~/Python-3.6.0 $ which python
/usr/bin/python
pi@raspberrypi:~/Python-3.6.0 $ ls -la /usr/bin/python
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 28 Mai 25 19:58 /usr/bin/python -> /home/pi/Python-3.6.0/python
pi@raspberrypi:~/Python-3.6.0 $
```

Does someone know what the mistake could be or/and a way to fix it?

Comment: "I run an install of Python3" **Why?** Python3 is already installed, admittedly `3.4.2`, but if you REALLY must install the latest why put in your home directory?

Comment: @Milliway Thank you for your fast reply! WTF... what have i done... I'm new to this topic and have forgotten to check. I enter `python --python` and receive 2.7.1 and i wanna updated to the current version. Can i remove the Python folder from my home directory ? Or will it contain some sideeffekts? If I run python3 ( from the `/urs/bin` directory - the preinstalled python3 version - I receive also the error info, in case of `python2`not. Why?

Comment: Who Knows? You haven't said **how** you installed, but there should be an uninstall option. Most normal installation methods wouldn't install in home.

Comment: To use Python 3 the command is python3.  How did you install Python 3.6?  RPi.GPIO works as expected with Python 3.42 as installed.

Comment: - tgz-File download, - extract, - run ./configuration, - make, -make install

Comment: but as i have seen - right now - the python3 verison is python 3.6.0 too

Comment: at the `usr/local/lib`folder is a `python3.4` located, is it a good practice to create in `usr/bin/`a symlink to this pythonversion ?

Comment: Change the link back to Python 3.4.  `cd /usr/bin; sudo rm python3; sudo ln -s python3.4 python3`

Comment: @joan Thank you for your fast and goal-orientated support ! Now it works!